# Track Click inside a iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-analytics, click

I want to track with a google analytics event the click on a href that is inside a iframe on my page. The iframe is in the same domain.
Is it possible? how?
The iframe is insert dynamically on the page after it loads. Is it important for this code to be put after the iframe?

Answer (score 1):

If the iframe is on your domain the contents of the iframe are propably under your control ( if it wasn't you wouldn't have any business tracking the frame). So you can simply install the Google Analytics tracking code in you iframe'd document (which you want to do anyway, after all a framed page is not very different from any other page on your website an you'll want to know how often it was called). So while you can access the parent frame from your (same origin) iframe (calling window.parent) it is not necessary or recommendable.

Answer (score 0):

If the iframe is the same domain, you can (from your main window) wait for the iframe to load and then install an event listener to handle the click on a particular link.

The code you will need is:

1. Code to wait for the iframe content to load.
2. Code to find the relevant link in the iframe
3. Code to install the event listener
4. Code to handler the click event